# Closed-form solution for the PV of these cash flows

Tags: quantitative, discounting, present-value

I've been trying to find a closed-form solution for the following equation, but without any progress.
[image]
I notice that the cash flows can be separated in: C1,C3,C5... which are 0; C2,C6,C10... negative; C4,C8,C12... positive. Detailed explanation would be highly appreciated.

Teacher's given solution:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool question!

In the following, I first use the fact that cosine of $\frac{\pi}{2}i$ is zero  for odd numbers. I then rewrite $\cos(\pi i)$ as $(-1)^i$. Then, I add the zeroth term, apply the well-known formula for an alternating geometric series
(Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+x}$) and simplify:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}i\right)}{(1+r)^i} &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}2i\right)}{(1+r)^{2i}} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{(1+r)^{2i}}\\
&=-1+\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i\left(\frac{1}{(1+r)^{2}}\right)^i\\
&=-1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{(1+r)^{2}}} \\
&=-\frac{1}{1+(r+1)^2}<0.
\end{align*}

See also [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5Einfinity+of+cos%28pi%2F2*i%29%2F%28%281%2Bx%29%5Ei%29).

As you see, the series is always negative. Assuming $C>0$, the PV  is always negative. Clearly, the series only converges if $r>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation of how to get to the final closed-form solution to this question, it's very helpful! I've also attached the final solution provided by the teacher and I was wondering if there's also a way of solving to obtain that as a final result :)